# Is Mithril the metal known as Aluminum?

Tags: tolkiens-legendarium, mithril

In *The Hobbit* and *The Lord of the Rings*, we are introduced to Mithril, a metal described as being stronger than steel but much lighter in weight.  It is also shown to have a silver sheen and the crafting of it is implied to require greater skill than steel.

Tolkien's works are often written in such a way as to create a real world mythological connection; Middle Earth is just our world in the distant past.

In modern times, [aluminum](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aluminium) and its alloys are used for many industrial purposes due to its light weight -- at 35 to 45% less weight than steel, when built to the same standards, it is considered much stronger per unit weight. It also has a nice silverish gleam when polished and was in use for over a century by the time of Tolkien's writings.

So, to the point: is there any counter proof to the theory that mithril may be the substance currently known as aluminum? I do not require a Word of God answer, but if there is one that would be great.

Comment: Take the tangential discussion to chat, folks.

Comment: Reminder: Mithril in the books doesn't violate physics; Frodo is stabbed by an Orc, not a troll, and is wearing a leather shirt under the mithril coat.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The main description of mithril I can find is this quote from Gandalf (also quoted [on the Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mithril) for the same):

> "Mithril! All folk desired it. It could be beaten like copper, and
>   polished like glass; and the Dwarves could make of it a metal, light
>   and yet harder than tempered steel. Its beauty was like to that of
>   common silver, but the beauty of mithril did not tarnish or grow dim."

Like mithril, aluminium:

- can be polished
- can be beaten
- can be made into strong alloys

However, aluminium *does* tarnish. Also, unlike gold, silver or copper, aluminium almost never occurs as a pure substance - it has to be refined from ore such as bauxite using energy-intensive processes unlikely to be possible in Tolkien's world.

So it's unlikely that aluminium is the same element that Tolkien calls "mithril".

Comment: I like(d) this, but *what if we don't have any pure aluminum because it all got mined up in previous ages?* Also, I don't know enough about aluminum alloys to name one that won't tarnish.

Comment: I think from the above quote it's fairly likely Gandalf is referring to the *pure substance* of mithril, not an alloy (since there can be many different alloys of any given metal that could have widely varying properties).

Comment: Also the scarcity of aluminium as a pure metal in nature is due to it's chemically reactive nature. This has always been the case.

Comment: @Yasskier are you asking why the answer refers to aluminium? Because that is the question posed by the OP: is mithril the same thing as aluminium. If you mean "could mithril be the same thing as titanium" then feel free to post that as a new question.